# Why the Gutenberg Editor is Not Available In My WP Site?

Tags: blog

I have been hearing a lot good about the Gutenberg but unfortunately, it's not available and might be disabled on my site https://grabhosts.net. It's a coupon site that is running by a WP Coupon theme by famethemes.

I have been using it for a while now and publishing various contents but i'm missing the best editor, Gutenberg.

I have checked the plugin and configured the settings too but there's no option to enable to functionality.
Here's a screenshot you can see.

[image]

The reason I want the Gutenberg editor is because of the FAQ schema and its advantages.
[image]

In case the theme has disabled this feature then if there's an alternative way to add faq schema to wp site then it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: We want you to [manually debug](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tags/debug/info) the issue, and [edit] the question to add the debug information, so that someone can help. Otherwise, the issue is too localized for anybody here to support you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare that your custom post type supports the `editor`, and have `show_in_rest` set to true when registering the post type.

Here is what the official dev hub says about `supports`:

> **'supports'**
>   (array) Core feature(s) the post type supports. Serves as an alias for calling add_post_type_support() directly. Core features include 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'revisions', 'trackbacks', 'author', 'excerpt', 'page-attributes', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', and 'post-formats'. Additionally, the 'revisions' feature dictates whether the post type will store revisions, and the 'comments' feature dictates whether the comments count will show on the edit screen. A feature can also be specified as an array of arguments to provide additional information about supporting that feature. Example: array( 'my_feature', array( 'field' => 'value' ) ). Default is an array containing 'title' and 'editor'.

If you don't, then WordPress will fall back to the classic editor